# How do I measure bytes in/out of an IP port used for .NET remoting?

Tags: .net, windows, networking, remoting

I am using .NET remoting to retrieve periodic status updates from a Windows service into a 'controller' application which is used to display some live stats about what the service is doing.

The resulting network traffic is huge - many times the size of the data for the updates - so clearly I have implemented the remoting code incorrectly in a very inefficient way. As a first step towards fixing it, I need to monitor the traffic on the IP port the service is using to talk to the controller, so that I can establish a baseline and then verify a fix.

Can anyone recommend a utility and/or coding technique that I can use to get the traffic stats? A "bytes sent" count for the port would suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is one of the best tools for capturing and analyzing IP traffic.

[Edit] Sort of lame that you answered first and didn't get the check mark.  I didn't mean to snake you.  +1 as a consolation.

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for traffic analysis.