# How to capture loopback traffic in Windows Server 2008

Tags: sockets, network-programming, windows-server-2008

Setup:

- I have client C connecting to server S
- Both C and S are on the same machine
- In C the server address is *hardcoded* to 127.0.0.1. Likewise, in S the client address is *hardcoded* to 127.0.0.1

Problem:
I want to be able to sniff the traffic between the client and the server.

- Due to the configuration, I cannot move the client nor the server to different locations (the address are hardcoded)
- Installing the loopback interface and using tools like Wireshark+WinPcap doesn't lead anywhere (was actually [already known](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) but was worth a try)
- RawCap, suggested in [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376/windows-packet-sniffer-that-can-capture-loopback-traffic), doesn't work. IP `127.0.0.1` is listed, but does not record any traffic.
- Using `rinetd` to route the traffic elsewhere, as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/91503/route-local-machine-traffic-to-gateway) doesn't work (cannot bind on 127.0.0.1)
- Not interested in using a HTTP local proxy, such as [Fiddler](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/localhost-http-debugging-with-fiddler.html), because I'd like to capture also other protocols
- Two commercial tools work, specifically [CommView](http://www.tamos.com/products/commview/) and [Local Network Monitor](http://www.ntkernel.com/w&p.php?id=24), which means it must be possible to do that ;)

How can I do to capture the traffic?
Any pointer on functions I should use or documentation I should read?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to write a TDI filter driver to achieve that... for some pointers see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565685%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563317%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Another option is to write a [WinSock LSP](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0599/LayeredService/LayeredService.aspx).

BEWARE
Since Windows 8 it is strongly encouraged to use [WFP (Windows Filtering Platform)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff570891.aspx) for this sort of thing...

Although it might be more cost-effective to just use/buy an existing solution - esp. if you are not a very experienced driver developer...

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I guess this is the best answer I have received so far, including answers IRL too :)

Answer (score 1):

Use RawCap, which can solve your concerns, see [this](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-04&post=RawCap-sniffer-for-Windows-released)

Comment: Not actually working. As I wrote in the description, in RawCap IP 127.0.0.1 is listed, but does not record any traffic.