# trace http session

Tags: http, trace

In a developement environement (where often the browser and the http server are on the same machine) i want to study the exact detail of authentication schemas. So i need to trace down every http request/response.

1. I've tried WireShark, that is very promising. But actually on
   windows machines there is a problem in sniffing the traffic on
   loopback interface.
2. Then i've tried a browser plugin, HttpFox
   0.8.10 of Firefox 12. It is good in showing requests and responses, but in the specific case of authentication, it doesn't correctly
   show the "double hop" authentication, it "collapses" the first
   request (the Unauthorized status code) with the next, successful
   one.
3. Then i've tried to work with the logs of httpd, that is my
   actual server, but it is required a not trivial effort to create a
   log that contains all the request such as headers (the authorization
   header).So it doesn't seem a good "debug" technique.

Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Have you tried Firebug on Firefox?

Comment: @nhahtdh, it's very nice, but debugs HTML, not http session. or am i missing something?

Comment: You can enable Net tab to see traffic in and out. Turn on Persist if you want to keep the log across navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with Wireshark. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376/windows-packet-sniffer-that-can-capture-loopback-traffic) will address the loopback issue. Wireshark is the best because it really understands the formatting of everything related to HTTP (so long as you are not using HTTPS).